# How to ensure bloc loaded state flutter

Tags: flutter, future, wait, do-while, bloc

I'm looking for a way to perform code after a certain bloc state is reached
for example:

```
Future<void> showOnboarding(emit, event) {
 // wait for a LoadedState
 emit(OnboardingState());
 emit(LoadedState());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to aproach this is using `Future.doWhile`

Example:

```
Future<void> showOnboarding(emit, event) async {
 // waiting for LoadedState
 await Future.doWhile(() async {
  if (state is LoadedState) return false;
  return true;
 });

 emit(OnboardingState());
 emit(LoadedState());
}
```